# Magento 2 Authorize.net payment failed issues

Tags: magento, magento2, authorize.net

I am using the Magento version 2.1.4. During checkout If my payment failed then mini cart become empty even there are item(s) in my cart. Does anyone have any idea about it?

During the search, I have found it is reported in Magento

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7854

Thank You!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?